# if more than one record on a column is populated with different values then use thevalue from different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to SQL and I tried to google this but I couldn't find an answer, hence posting here. Any help is appreciated.

My table is:

[image]

My output should look like this:

[image]

My output should be based on the conditions below :

1. If more than one record is populated for same NID with different values(other than null) in "val " column,  , then use Val where Typ= T.
2. For same NID, if there is null value for Typ "T", then get "Val" where Typ=O
3. For Same NID, if there is null value for Typ "O", then get "Val" where Typ=T

Comment: It would be better to provide your tables as formatted text.

Comment: And what have you tried???

Comment: [Write this query for me](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @Eric what do you mean????

Comment: @user28455 Which part of my question is not clear???  Where's your query???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.  Let me know if it does what you are looking for or not.

```
SELECT TT.NID
    , COALESCE(TT.Val, OO.Val) AS Val
FROM 
(
    SELECT T.NID
        , T.Val
    FROM [SomeTable] T
    WHERE T.Typ = 'T'
) TT
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT O.NID
        , O.Val
    FROM [SomeTable] O
    WHERE O.Typ = 'O'
) OO
    ON TT.NID = OO.NID
```